# passing arguments and returns between c# application and c++ exe file

Tags: c#, c++

I want to call an c++ exe file into my c# application that takes a command line argument and returns the result so that i can use it in my c# application but i don't know how to do it .

here's the simple sample that i tried and failed : 
c++ code : returner.exe

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(string argc , string argv)
{
    int b= atoi(argv.c_str());
    return b;
}
```

c# code :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo stf = new ProcessStartInfo("returner.exe", "3");
            stf.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            stf.UseShellExecute = false; 
            stf.CreateNoWindow = true;

            using (Process p = Process.Start(stf))
            {
                p.WaitForExit();
                int a = p.ExitCode;
                label1.Text = a.ToString();
            }
        }
```

i expect to see 3 in the lable . but it's always 0 . what should i do ?

Comment: Perhaps a C++-made DLL would better suit your purposes.

Comment: Is your C++ code even valid? That `main` signature is not standard.

Comment: Have you, maybe,  considered debugging at all?  What happens if your C++ main explicitly returns '3', ie. ignores the 'main' parameters, (which I'm not at all happy with - see Mat comment).

Comment: I'm not an expert in c++ so if you know how to write c++ code tell me . yes if my c++ code explicitly returns 3 i would see 3 in label .

Comment: `int main(int argc, const char** argv)` -> this is a correct prototype for the main function. From that you should perhaps be able to do something

Comment: I knew it , but if i do so , the parameter is char** and i pass a string to it . what about that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of your `main` is incorrect, it should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // you are better to verify that argc == 2, otherwise it's UB.
    int b= atoi(argv[1]);
    return b;
}
```